# Is there a way to wrap an object up as a ConcurrentObject?

Tags: c#, object, concurrency, .net-4.5

I know how to utilize the `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` class by using a `GetOrAdd()` method very nicely. Is there a similar class for a single object instead? I'd rather not create a dictionary for a single object just to get concurrency.

---

Right now, I'm doing the following:

```
return _singledict.GetOrAdd(_sync, CreateSingleItem);
```

Comment: Note, that GetOrAdd might invoke the factory multiple times for the same key. All but one result will be thrown away.

Comment: Do you really need the effect of `GetOrAdd`, or do you simply want to return a new `KeyValuePair` each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have some means of accessing an existing object if it has already been constructed, and constructing a new one if it hasn't been, with the appropriate tools in place to prevent the construction of multiple objects.

This is exactly what `Lazy<T>` exists for.